# JavaScript best practice prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have a function in the prototype of the constructor:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype.generateToys = function(numberOfToys) {
  if(numberOfToys == 1) {
    this.createToys();
  } 
  else {
    this.createToys();
  }
}
```

The `createToys` still needs to be declared. And that´s where my question is pointing towards. Assuming that `generateToys` will be the only method that will call `createToys()`, would it be better to create `createToys` inside the method `generateToys` like so:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype.generateToys = function(numberOfToys) {
  if(numberOfToys == 1) {
    this.createToys();
  } 
  else {
    this.createToys();
  }

  function createToys() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Or would you create it as a method(prototype) like the following:

```
Animal.prototype.createToys = function() {
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

What would be better and why? :)

Comment: depends. Do you want any instance of your object to have direct access to createToys? or do you want them to go through generateToys? Since you have an if inside generateToys, I am guessing you want them to always go through generateToys so the function should be private

Comment: The best solution is the one that works. Your first suggestion doesn't make `createToys` a property on the instance, so calling `this.createToys()` will fail (i.e. it does not work). But even if you fixed that, why does `createToys` have to be recreated every time `generateToys` is called? That seems unnecessary (at least given your example). Define the function once. Where you do it (`prototype`, function outside the "class") doesn't really matter.

Comment: I advice you to have a look at a talk of Douglas Crockford, Function The Ultimate ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM ), it exposes various ways to work with objects creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put it inside the `generateToys()` method, it will be re-declared every single time you call that method, and then be removed from scope when the method completes.  Most of the time this isn't what you want, so you'd prefer to create it as a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your architecture.

If you plan to have many instances of `Animal` then adding your method to the prototype is better, otherwise you will be creating a lot of private functions and that is costly (in terms of performance).

Answer (score 1):

declaring the function inside the prototype limits the visibility outside that scope and cause the function to be declared everytime you call `Animal.prototype.generateToys()` (waste of memory)

```
Animal.prototype.generateToys = function(numberOfToys) {
   var createToys = function createToys() { 

   }

})
```

declaring it on the prototype means that each of your instance can call it directly and you will have only one spot in memory with that declaration because the prototype itself it's a single reference shared by all your instances.